# ssh error 127 with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I get the following console output while running a job on Jenkins:

**Building in workspace /home/admin/.jenkins/jobs/ramdisk/workspace

[SSH] executing pre build script:

./build_script.sh

[SSH] exit-status: 127

[SSH] executing post build script:

[SSH] exit-status: 0

Finished: SUCCESS**

When I run the above script manually on a terminal, it is fine.
Can you please guide what could be the issue here?

Comment: What are the differences between running the script in Jenkins and by yourself? Is it the user, the path or the machine or smth. else?

Comment: When I run directly on my machine, ./build_script runs succesfully the desired instructions written in it.
But via Jenkins, it (./build_script.sh) gives [SSH] exit-status: 127 and does not do anything mentioned inside the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you run script manually on the terminal, you could be getting exit status 127 as well, but since you are not checking the exit status on terminal, you are not noticing it.

Jenkins assumes that only exit code of 0 means success. Any other exit code means some failure. If your build_script.sh uses exit codes in non-standard way, it will make Jenkins think that it had failed.

Do the following directly on the machine:

```
./build_script.sh
echo $?
```

Make sure you do the echo command immediately after the script command, without doing anything else. This will print the exit code on the command line. Answer here what you get.

Second, open the build_script.sh in a text editor (vim, nano, whatever you use) and search for `exit 127`. If you find it, see what block does it exit from. If you got trouble reading the script, paste the content of the script (or just the block where you found `exit 127`) in here, and we could tell you why the script thinks it needs to exit.